# Mouse Wheel Event and Scroll Event conflicting with eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

My Problem is this:

I have a MouseWheel Event (from plugin: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) that triggers a function:

```
$(document).on('mousewheel', onMouseWheel);

function onMouseWheel(event,delta)
{ Code... }
```

I Also have a Scroll Event that triggers another function:

```
$(document).on('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll()
{ Code... }
```

However when using the mouswheel, both events are triggered and so both functions run, which I don't want them to. They have to be separate since using the mousewheel and dragging the scrollbar should give separate results. The problem only occurs that way around ie. the mousewheel function is not triggered by dragging the scrollbar.

EDIT:

I've realized with a little help, that the problem occurs because I use ScrollLeft() inside my mousewheel function, which of course causes the scroll event.

I've tried to think of a solution but with no luck. Can anyone help? Thanks!

EDIT: More code:

```
$(document).on('scroll', onScroll );

            function onScroll()
            {
                code...
            }


            $(document).on('mousewheel', onMouseWheel ) );

            function onMouseWheel(event,delta)
            {
                event.preventDefault(); 

                if(delta<0)
                {       
                    detectDown();       
                }

                else if(delta>0)
                {
                    detectUp();
                }

                return false;   
            }


            $(document).on("keydown", onKeyDown);

            function onKeyDown(e)
            {
                event.preventDefault();

                if (e.keyCode == 37) 
                { 
                    detectUp();
                }
                else if (e.keyCode == 39)
                {
                    detectDown();   
                }

            }


            function detectUp()
            {
                $("html, body").animate({scrollLeft:(currentElement.prev().position().left - 100)}, 800, 'easeOutQuad'); 
                currentElement = currentElement.prev();
            }

            function detectDown()
            {
                $("html, body").animate({scrollLeft:(currentElement.next().position().left - 100)}, 800, 'easeOutQuad'); 

            }
```

Maybe this helps?

Comment: Have you tried `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` on mouse wheel event.

Comment: Thanks but no it didn't help. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I've added more code, so you can see the context.

Answer (score 2):

Add `return false` at the end of the `onMouseWheel` function.

```
function onMouseWheel(event, delta) {
  // code
  return false;
}
```

This will disable the default scroll action for the `'mousewheel'` event, hence the `'scroll'` event will not be triggered.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6NwR/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I already have an event.preventDefault();. Because of your comment, however, I've realized that I have a ScrollLeft() inside the mousewheel function which of course causes the problem. Is there anyway out of this mess?

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the realization, that the best solution is to make a custom scrollbar. This way we can avoid calling the scrolling function and having the different types of scrolling interfering with one another.